# How to get the Server instance in Streamlit version 1.12?

Tags: streamlit

Until version `1.11`, `Streamlit` had the following way to access the current Server instance:

```
from streamlit.server.server import Server

Server.get_current()
```

Now, in version `1.12`, it changed to:

```
from streamlit.web.server import Server
```

It's ok. But the method `get_current()` was removed from the class `Server`.

So, is there another way to get the server instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They removed the singleton in [this PR](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/pull/4966/files).

Here is one internal way to access the object, by fetching it from the closure variables of a signal handler that streamlit registers in its run() method:

```py
import typing as T
from streamlit.web.server import Server

def get_streamlit_server() -> T.Optional[Server]:
    """
    Get the active streamlit server object. Must be called within a running
    streamlit session.

    Easy access to this object was removed in streamlit 1.12:
        https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/pull/4966
    """
    # In the run() method in `streamlit/web/bootstrap.py`, a signal handler is registered
    # with the server as a closure. Fetch that signal handler.
    streamlit_signal_handler = signal.getsignal(signal.SIGQUIT)

    # Iterate through the closure variables and return the server if found.
    for cell in streamlit_signal_handler.__closure__:
        if isinstance(cell.cell_contents, Server):
            return cell.cell_contents

    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

In case there is no other way (if there is, please tell me), the server instance can be found in the object list of the garbage collector:

```
import gc

for obj in gc.get_objects():
    if type(obj) is Server:
        server = obj
        break
```